# How to redefine c++ pointer function?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, android-ndk

I have code from BASS lib.

```
#ifndef BASSDEF
#define BASSDEF(f) WINAPI f
#else
#define NOBASSOVERLOADS
#endif

HSAMPLE BASSDEF(BASS_SampleLoad)(BOOL mem, const void *file, QWORD offset, DWORD length, DWORD max, DWORD flags);
```

I need redefine BASSDEF to call dlsym function. How can i do this?

**Update**:
I using this on Android NDK (Linux) i loaded bass module via function dlopen and i need to make all functions point (here is original header file of bass lib https://pastebin.com/Z2Ty9UsY ) to this loaded module via dlsym function. I need this to call all functions (from JNI inside bass.so) module easily.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "dlsym function".

Comment: @SebastianRedl https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I know `dlsym` in Linux. But this is Windows. Also, "dlsym function" is not a well-defined term. Neither is "GetProcAddress function", the Windows translation.

Comment: @SebastianRedl _"But this is Windows"_ Where does the question say that?

Comment: @SebastianRedl _"Also, 'dlsym function' is not a well-defined term"_ Come on, that's _really_ stretching credulity.

Comment: `BASSDEF` is not a function, and neither it nor `BASS_SampleLoad` is a pointer. Please be more specific about what you want to accomplish and what the context is.

Comment: I using this on Android NDK (Linux) i loaded bass module via function dlopen and i need to make all functions point to this loaded module via dlsym function.

Comment: Description updated.

Comment: @SebastianRedl take a look at BASS lib description and provided header. BASS is cross-platform. For example in linux impl WINAPI redefined as nothing to be just a placeholder. So, it only looks like Windows-only!

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica "Come on, that's really stretching credulity" - No, I genuinely have no idea what "call dlsym function" means. Is the OP just confused about DLLs vs runtime linking (as opposed to load-time) and means "import from DLL"? (E.g. redefine `BASSDEF` to invoke the corerct `__declspec(dllimport)` magic?) Or do they want the function declaration to turn into a function pointer global that is initialized via `dlsym/GetProcAddress`? It could be either, or something else. "dlsym function" is not a defined term that would clarify this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, BASSDEF is not a function. It's macro which is known at compile time. So let's unwrap it ourselves:

```
HSAMPLE WINAPI BASS_SampleLoad(BOOL mem, const void *file, QWORD offset, DWORD length, DWORD max, DWORD flags);
```

Whoa, just function declaration here. Now "WINAPI" is basicly __stdcall call convention (Microsoft-specific). But, looking to BASS header you provided one can find for non-WIN32 systems:

```
#define WINAPI
```

Basicly, under Linux it's just a placeholder which expands to nothing. Now function declaration looks like this:

```
HSAMPLE BASS_SampleLoad(BOOL mem, const void *file, QWORD offset, DWORD length, DWORD max, DWORD flags);
```

What's next? You would like to find this function in some shared library via **dlsym**?

I assume you wants something like this:

```
// Declare a function pointer in C++11 style
using BASS_SampleLoad_FuncPtr = std::add_pointer<decltype(BASS_SampleLoad)>::type;
// Open library you wants
void* soHandle = dlopen("your_lib_here.so", RTLD_LAZY);
// Error check!
if (nullptr == soHandle) {
    // Fail here
}
// Finally, get pointe to function!
BASS_SampleLoad_FuncPtr BASS_SampleLoad = reinterpret_cast<BASS_SampleLoad_FuncPtr>(dlsym(soHandle, "BASS_SampleLoad"));
// Error check!
if (nullptr == BASS_SampleLoad) {
    // Fail here
}
// Now only here it's safe to call "BASS_SampleLoad" with required params
auto sample = BASS_SampleLoad(...);

...

// Don't forget to close lib
dlclose(soHandle);
```

Please, NOTE!
Provided code is not tested and might contain errors. And, it's C++11 standard.

Also, for C++14 and higher replace '*std::add_pointer<...>::type*' with '*std::add_pointer_t<...>*'

**P.S. this code valid because BASS is cross-platform library and all WinAPI-look-a-like stuff (WINAPI, QWORD, BOOL, DWORD, etc.) is defined for Linux in BASS header**

Comment: It works only if use using decltype, thanks for the answer.

BASS_SampleLoad_FuncPtr = std::add_pointer<decltype(BASS_SampleLoad)>::type;